# how to refreshing datatables (jquery plug in) without reload page

Tags: jquery, ajax, datatable

please help me, i'm very newbie
i have question about [datatables (jquery plug in)](http://www.datatables.net).

at every rows data in datatables grid, I have button to delete data.
when i click delete button, data at that row deleted.

the question is, can I refresh data table without reloading the page ?
so the rows can be decrease when i click delete button without reloading the page.

this is my code: (just FYI my table id for datatble is: id="mydatatable")

```
html delete button on each rows data:
-------------------------------------

<button onclick="delete('id')">Delete</button>


javascript:
-----------

delete(id)
{
    delete_ajax(id);            //deleting data using ajax

    window.location.reload()    //reloading page, this what i want to change 
                                //(just refresh datatable grid without reload the page)
}
```

many thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at the api.  You should be able to call fnDeleteRow on your datatables object.

http://www.datatables.net/api

Comment: actually i'm not just need for delete only, but also for add and edit. so maybe i need for refreshing the datatables :)

Comment: Click through to the linked documentation.  There's fnAddData and fnUpdate which will likely fit your need.

Answer (score 5):

This is one of many ways to quickly refresh a table

```
const table=$("table.datatable").dataTable();
table.fnPageChange("first",1);
```

Answer (score 1):

if your `delete_ajax()` function is handling the business logic and if you want to remove the current row you can easily remove the row using `$('rowobject').hide().`

Comment: Here i am assuming you are using jQuery for javascript processing as you have used jquery in tags. $('rowobject') is current row's object

Answer (score 1):

This will do the trick ->

oTable.fnDraw(false);

U can call like this

```
     setInterval(function ref(){
    oTable.fnDraw(false);
    },8000);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to reload the current page data, you can use this code.

```
table.ajax.reload();
```

Please refer to this [DataTable ajax.reload()](https://datatables.net/reference/api/ajax.reload())

Answer (score 0):

We can use DataTable API.

```
var currentPage = ListTable.page();

ListTable.page(0).draw( 'page' );
```